# Using async with a polymorphic member function

Tags: c++, design-patterns, asynchronous, c++11, observer-pattern

Trying to create an asyncronous Observer pattern is causing a compiler error C3867, which I am clueless how to resolve it. The sample code snippet is as follows

```
class Subject;

class Observer
{
public:
    virtual void notify(Subject* s) = 0;
    virtual ~Observer() {};
};

class Subject
{
    std::map<std::string, Observer *> observers;
protected:
    void notify_observers()
    {
        std::map<std::string, Observer *>::iterator iter;
        for (iter = observers.begin(); iter != observers.end(); ++iter) {
            void (Observer::*notify)(Subject *) = iter->second->notify;
            std::async(std::launch::async, notify, this);
        }
    }

public:
    virtual ~Subject() {};
    void observer(std::string id, Observer* o)
    {
        observers[id] = o;
    }
};

template<typename Iter, typename type>
class Sort : public Observer {
public:
    virtual void notify(Subject* s)
    {
        TestSort<Iter> *a;
        a = dynamic_cast<TestSort<Iter> *>(s);
        std::vector<type> temp(a->beg(), a->end());

        sort(temp->beg(), temp->end());
    }
};

template<typename Iter, typename type>
class InsertionSort : public Sort<Iter, type>
{
    void sort(Iter beg, Iter end) {
        for (Iter i = beg; i != end; ++i)
            std::rotate(std::upper_bound(beg, i, *i), i, i+1);
    }


};
int main ()
{
    std::vector<double> data(100);
    std::generate(data.begin(), data.end(), [](){return rand() % 500;} ); 
    auto ts = TestSort<std::vector<double>::iterator >(data.begin(), data.end());

    auto is = new InsertionSort<std::vector<double>::iterator, double >();
    //.................
    ts.observer("InsertionSort", is);
    //.........................
    ts.Triggerd();
    return 0;
}
```

Though I understand the error

```
 error C3867: 'Observer::notify': function call missing argument list; use '&Observer::notify' to create a pointer to member
```

Yet in this context I cannot figure out, how to resolve it.

In this context, if notify would had been a simply addreesable member function, instead of

```
void (Observer::*notify)(Subject *) = iter->second->notify;
```

I could have simply write

```
void (Observer::*notify)(Subject *) = &Observer::notify;
```

But notify is a polymorphic function and I cannot address the right function during compile time.

Please suggest how should I process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
void (Observer::*notify)(Subject *) = iter->second->notify;
std::async(std::launch::async, notify, this);
```

To:

```
void (Observer::*notify)(Subject *) = &Observer::notify;
std::async(std::launch::async, std::mem_fun(notify), iter->second, this);
```

When you call a method, you need both the pointer-to-instance and arguments.  The standard syntax is `rettype retval = instance->method(arg);`, but `std::mem_fun` will return a functor you can use like `rettype retval = std::mem_fun(&InstanceType::method)(instance, arg);` -- it makes the implicit `this` pointer passed to a member function explicit.

From a pointer to a `virtual` method, plus an object pointer, `std::mem_fun` can figure out which instance of the `virtual` method you should call.

A similar thing can be done with a `bind` or a lambda.  Here is a roughly equivalent call using lambda syntax:

```
 Observer* observer = iter->second;
 std::async(std::launch::async, [observer,this]() { observer->notify(this); } );
```

See the comment below: you don't have to use `std::mem_fun`, `async` will do it for you.  You do have to pass the instance pointer of the member function as the next argument still.

Comment: There's no need to use `mem_fn`, `async` knows what to do with pointers-to-member-functions, so just say: `std::async(std::launch::async, notify, iter->second, this)`

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to figure out the right function during compile time, just as you don't have to figure it out for regular virtual function call. Just use `&Observer::notify`. The right function is selected at the time of *call*, not at the time of taking its address.